# Set image format of field_view_field image field

Tags: nodes, entities, hooks, users, theming

I'm using a function to place an image from a user field into nodes that the user creates. The display is set to thumbnail in default, user account and tokens, but it shows up as original in the node. Is there a way I can set the format in the function I'm using somehow?

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  $user = user_load($node->uid);

  $logo_var = field_view_field('user', $user, 'field_business_logo');
  $logo_print_var = drupal_render($logo_var[0]);
  $vars['logo_print_var'] = $logo_print_var;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set the field value display settings as a parameter to [`field_view_field`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_field/7)

e.g:

```
// Customize field display settings.
$display_settings = array(
  'label' => 'hidden',
  'settings' => array(
    'field_multiple_limit' => '1',
    'field_multiple_limit_offset' => '0',
    'image_link' => 'content',
    'image_style' => 'thumbnail',
  ),
  'type' => 'image',
  'weight' => 0,
);
// Get field value
$logo_var = field_view_field('user', $user, 'field_business_logo', $display_settings);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I knew it probably involved using an array. Still getting the hang of drupal theming/php in general. Never would've figured that out, haha.